# Error installing and using numpy

Tags: python, unicode, numpy, debian

I'm having unicode troubles trying to run numpy.

As pointed [here](http://mail.scipy.org/pipermail/numpy-discussion/2010-January/048072.html) and and [here](http://www.mail-archive.com/numpy-discussion@scipy.org/msg11229.html) i'm using python with 4 bytes unicode, I downloaded the numpy 1.6.1 source code and run the python installer:

in the numpy source directory:

```
which python
/usr/local/bin/python
python -c 'import sys; print sys.maxunicode'
1114111
python setup.py build
python setup.py install
cd ~
python -c 'import numpy'

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/site-packages/numpy/__init__.py", line 137, in
<module>
    import add_newdocs
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/site-packages/numpy/add_newdocs.py", line 9, 
in <module>
    from lib import add_newdoc
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/site-packages/numpy/lib/__init__.py", line 4,
in <module>
    from type_check import *
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/site-packages/numpy/lib/type_check.py", line 
8, in <module>
    import numpy.core.numeric as _nx
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/site-packages/numpy/core/__init__.py", 
line 5, in <module>
    import multiarray
ImportError: /usr/local/lib/python2.6/site-packages/numpy/core/multiarray.so:
undefined symbol: PyUnicodeUCS2_AsASCIIString
```

Since i'm compiling numpy with 4-bytes python unicode support, I don´t get why i'm having the 2-bytes unicode error in numpy

Environment:

- Debian 6 64 bits
- Python 2.6.8
- Numpy 1.6.1

Any clues on this will be apreciated

Comment: Is the python-numpy package already available in Debian insufficient for your needs?

Comment: @kwatford actually no, I need numpy to get nupic (http://www.numenta.com/archives/software.php) to work

Comment: In that case, you can't use Python 2.6.8 either. NuPIC's requirements page demands 2.5.4, and explicitly notes that 2.6 isn't going to work. Check their requirements page for specific compilation requirements.

Comment: @kwatford thanks!, actually NuPIC works on further versions of python. Somehow I managed to get this working: had a very messy environment and starting from scratch was the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somehow I managed to get this working: had a very messy environment and starting from scratch was the solution.