# ImportError: No module named numpy

Tags: python, numpy

I'm trying to run a program that requires Numpy to be installed. I thought it was, because if I try `sudo apt-get install python-numpy` it tells me that

```
sudo apt-get install python-numpy

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
python-numpy is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

But then when I go to install the program I'm trying to (within that programs directory, where setup.py is located) I get:

```
python setup.py install
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "setup.py", line 20, in <module>
    from weblogolib import __version__
  File "/home/chris/Documents/IS/Bioinformatics-Software/weblogo-3.3/weblogolib/__init__.py", line 108, in <module>
     from numpy import array, asarray, float64, ones, zeros, int32,all,any, shape
ImportError: No module named numpy
```

When I look in the Python-2.7.3/Lib/site-packages directory the only thing that's in there is a README file. Shouldn't there be stuff from Numpy in there (and other install Python modules)?

I am running Ubuntu 12.04 with Python 2.7

Using `dpkg -l python-numpy` I get:

```
Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
||/ Name           Version        Description
+++-==============-==============-============================================
ii  python-numpy   1:1.6.1-6ubunt Numerical Python adds a fast array facility
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You do not mention where you are running the commands.  For the commands, I guess you are using `Ubuntu 12.10`.

In Ubuntu 12.10 the default is Python3 (check it with `python --version`).  So that, when you ran `python setup ...`, you are running it with the default python available.  For what it is worth, weblog 3.3 requires Python 2.5, 2.6 or 2.7.

Also, you can check where python-numpy was installed (check it with `dpkg -L python-numpy`).

My shot out of the blue would be:

```
$ python2.7 setup.py install
```

If you do not have installed python2.7, you should install it (likely, the shell is going to suggest it).

Comment: Hey, I have python 2.7 and Ubuntu 12.04. I added the results of trying `dpkg -l python-numpy` to my original post. I'm not sure but I think that says it's not installed?

Comment: I'm sorry, I meant `dpkg -L python-numpy`.  It is installed (`ii`), also you already said you had installed.  I just wanted you to check where the files were installed.

Comment: Seems like most of it is in /usr/lib/python2.7/ but since it's definitely installed I feel like that makes the results of the `python setup.py install` line all the more perplexing lol

Comment: Did you try `python --version` to check the version of python you are running by default?.  Also check if you have defined the environment variable `PYTHONPATH`, which may be pointing out to a different place.

Comment: Version 2.7.3 so I'm good on that one. But checking my `PYTHONPATH` (which took awhile to figure out how to do lol) I see that dist-packages is not in there, and apparently that's where Python sticks new modules after version 2.6, so I need to add that `Python2.7/dist-packages` directory to the PYTHONPATH variable. I'm trying to figure out how but I'm having trouble haha

Comment: you can either unset it (`unset PYTHONPATH`), add a new path (`export PYTHONPATH=/new/path/to/add:$PYTHONPATH`) or replace the whole content (`export PYTHONPATH=/path/1/I/want:/path/2/I/want`).  But, if you have Python packages installed in your HOME, you want to add them in your `PYTHONPATH` as well.

Comment: Got it, just added to the existing `PYTHONPATH`. So I tried the `python setup.py install` again, and didn't get the same error. I got `ImportError: /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/core/multiarray.so: undefined symbol: PyUnicodeUCS4_AsUnicodeEscapeString` But the numpy not being found has been resolved I guess. Thanks for your help. Should I just make a new topic for this new and exciting error?

Comment: It seems the problem has been reported in the past.  Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10322937/error-installing-and-using-numpy and http://effbot.org/pyfaq/when-importing-module-x-why-do-i-get-undefined-symbol-pyunicodeucs2.htm  Maybe you have a mix of packages.

Comment: Ah I see the issue. Well that's irritating. I guess Python uses 2-byte unicode characters, but this version of numpy I've download is using 4-byte unicode characters. It seems odd that an extension specifically made for Python wouldn't use a compatible format. Anyhow,I have to go find a compatible numpy version. Thanks for your help, you've saved me tons of time floundering about haha.

Answer (score 4):

I solved it by using following command to install the numpy module in my Ubuntu system.

On debian/ubuntu:

```
aptitude install python-numpy
```