# Possible conflicting python installations

Tags: python, numpy

I'm not sure if the default python installation is the one that I've been installing modules to, and if that may be the cause of a conflicting Unicode byte size compatibility error. In short, I've installed Numpy 1.7 using Python 2.7.3 and when I try to install this other program that uses Python and Numpy as dependencies, I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 20, in <module>
    from weblogolib import __version__
  File "/home/chris/Documents/IS/Bioinformatics-Software/weblogo-3.3/weblogolib/__init__.py", line 108, in <module>
    from numpy import array, asarray, float64, ones, zeros, int32,all,any, shape
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/__init__.py", line 137, in <module>
import add_newdocs
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/add_newdocs.py", line 9, in <module>
from numpy.lib import add_newdoc
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/lib/__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
from type_check import *
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/lib/type_check.py", line 8, in <module>
import numpy.core.numeric as _nx
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/core/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
import multiarray
ImportError: /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/core/multiarray.so: undefined symbol: PyUnicodeUCS4_AsUnicodeEscapeString
```

So I guess I have a conflicting unicode byte size (2-byte vs. 4-byte). I went to check to see if I had conflicting versions of Python that could be messing this up.

```
python --version
Python 2.7.3
```

But this seems at odds with

```
which python
/usr/local/bin/python
```

When I go to `/usr/local/bin` I find these files (relevant to python):

```
python
python2
python2.7
python-config
python2-config
python2.7-config
```

Now I've installed numpy into the dist-packages directory of `/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages` which corresponds to what I get for `python --version`. But the fact that when I try `which python` and get a directory for `python` and not `python2.7` concerns me that this might be conflicting when I try to install the program that uses python and numpy as dependencies.

So I guess to clarify my question(s): Are these normal files to find for a python installation or have I somehow installed three different versions? Could they be causing my error with the unrecognized symbol? Is there a way to uninstall if they are indeed extraneous versions?

Thanks for any help you can provide!

Oh and here is a link to a previous question I had, where I edited the `PYTHONPATH` while trying to fix an ImportError I was getting, if that might be affecting things....[ImportError: No module named numpy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15401411/importerror-no-module-named-numpy/15401553?noredirect=1#comment21775367_15401553)

Here are the results of trying virtualenv:

```
chris@ubuntu:~/Documents/IS/Bioinformatics-Software$ virtualenv weblogo-3.3
New python executable in weblogo-3.3/bin/python
Installing setuptools.............done.
Installing pip...............done.
chris@ubuntu:~/Documents/IS/Bioinformatics-Software$ cd weblogo-3.3
chris@ubuntu:~/Documents/IS/Bioinformatics-Software/weblogo-3.3$ source bin/activate
(weblogo-3.3)chris@ubuntu:~/Documents/IS/Bioinformatics-Software/weblogo-3.3$ pip install numpy
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): numpy in /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
Cleaning up...
```

Comment: `/usr/local/bin/python` is probably just a symlink.  use `ls -l /usr/local/bin/python` to see where

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The problem indeed seems to be a mismatch of Python and Numpy compile settings.

/usr/local/bin is where custom Python is installed, you should try to run using /usr/bin/python instead.

Another solution is to use a virtualenv.  Try this:

```
virtualenv myproject
cd myproject
source bin/activate
pip install numpy
```

Basically virtualenv sets up a different Python installation with its own packages in the "myproject" directory.  Running the "activate" command tells the system that you want to use this installation instead of the default system.  This lets you have a different Python environment for different projects.  Using virtualenv, each project can have its own versions of Python packages even if they're incompatible with other projects or system packages.

Note you will have to repeat the "source" command each time you open a new shell and want to use that virtual environment.  Also you might have to install the virtualenv command by using your OS package manager.  If this isn't possible (e.g. you don't have root access) or your OS version is too old for some reason, you can also download it manually from https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/v/virtualenv/

If you do ls -l /usr/local/bin/python* you should see that python and python2 are actually symlinks to python2.7, and likewise python-config and python2-config are symlinks to python2.7-config.

Comment: Hey, thanks for that explanation - I had actually tried to use virtualenv when I realized, but couldn't figure out how to get it working. I tried `pip install numpy` and edited my original post with the results. Basically it's still using the previously installed version of numpy.

Comment: Okay, I just tried `python setup.py install` and it ran this time without apparent errors, despite using the same installation of Numpy as outside of the virtualenvironment. I guess this works for now, although I'd like to ultimately resolve conflicting installations if they're present....but anyway thanks for your help

Comment: If virtualenv is finding your system-wide numpy, doing "virtualenv --no-site-packages myproject" might help.  For me, "man virtualenv" says this option is the default, but this might not be the case for you if you're using an older version.

Answer (score 1):

What OS are you on?  This is more a question for superuser, but try something like this.   Ditch `easy_install` and use `pip` if you haven't already.

On Ubuntu:

```
sudo apt-get install python-setuptools 
sudo easy_install pip 
pip install --user numpy
```

Comment: Yeah I tried using `pip` rather than `easy_install` but still got the same problem.