# Can't get Theano to work on ubuntu 14.04

Tags: python, ubuntu, numpy, theano

I'm trying to use Theano on ubuntu 14.04, I've followed the guide for an easy install located here http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/install_ubuntu.html#install-ubuntu

Everything says it's installed fine, if I run:

```
sudo apt-get install python-numpy python-scipy python-dev python-pip python-nose g++ libopenblas-dev git
```

Then I get in return

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree 
Reading state information... Done
g++ is already the newest version.
git is already the newest version.
python-dev is already the newest version.
python-nose is already the newest version.
python-numpy is already the newest version.
libopenblas-dev is already the newest version.
python-pip is already the newest version.
python-scipy is already the newest version.
0 to upgrade, 0 to newly install, 0 to remove and 18 not to upgrade.
```

And when running

```
sudo pip install Theano
```

I get

```
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): Theano in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): numpy>=1.5.0 in ./.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from Theano)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): scipy>=0.7.2 in /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from Theano)
Cleaning up...
```

But when I go to run the tests they just don't work.

```
python -c "import numpy; numpy.test()"
```

gives me

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/josh/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/__init__.py", line 153, in <module>
    from . import add_newdocs
  File "/home/josh/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/add_newdocs.py", line 13, in <module>
    from numpy.lib import add_newdoc
  File "/home/josh/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/lib/__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from .type_check import *
  File "/home/josh/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/lib/type_check.py", line 11, in <module>
    import numpy.core.numeric as _nx
  File "/home/josh/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    from . import multiarray
ImportError: /home/josh/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/multiarray.so: undefined symbol: PyUnicodeUCS4_AsUnicodeEscapeString
```

and

```
python -c "import scipy; scipy.test()"
```

gives me

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named scipy
```

The last test gives very similar results

```
josh@josh-GA-78LMT-S2P:~$ python -c "import theano; theano.test()"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named theano
```

I'm a complete linux newbie so I'm completely baffled by what could be the problem.

Comment: Possibly the same issue as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15403273/possible-conflicting-python-installations

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can, I would simply use a "scientific" Python - either [Anaconda](https://store.continuum.io/cshop/anaconda/) (my preference) or Enthought Python. In addition to avoiding systemwide installation of packages, it is easy to install things with pip and numpy and scipy come preinstalled. For updating numpy and scipy you can also use the built-in conda package manager - it does an excellent job of handling the nasty work behind installing a new numpy or scipy.

Comment: This seems to have done the job nicely, thanks a lot!