# pip is not working , even though it is properly installed

Tags: python, pip, easy-install

I am trying to setup pip for linux .
I have python 12.7.12 on the system , pip is installed on the system

```
~/Desktop # sudo easy_install pip
 install_dir /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/
 Searching for pip
 Best match: pip 9.0.1
 Processing pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg
 pip 9.0.1 is already the active version in easy-install.pth
 Installing pip script to /usr/local/bin
 Installing pip2.7 script to /usr/local/bin
 Installing pip2 script to /usr/local/bin
```

from here it looks pip is installed properly , but when i am trying to use pip then it throws error .

```
    pip -V
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/local/bin/pip", line 9, in <module>
    load_entry_point('pip==9.0.1', 'console_scripts', 'pip')()
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/distribute-0.6.14-py2.7.egg/pkg_resources.py", line 305, in load_entry_point
    return get_distribution(dist).load_entry_point(group, name)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/distribute-0.6.14-py2.7.egg/pkg_resources.py", line 2244, in load_entry_point
    return ep.load()
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/distribute-0.6.14-py2.7.egg/pkg_resources.py", line 1954, in load
    entry = __import__(self.module_name, globals(),globals(), ['__name__'])
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/__init__.py", line 28, in <module>
    from pip.vcs import git, mercurial, subversion, bazaar  # noqa
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/vcs/mercurial.py", line 9, in <module>
    from pip.download import path_to_url
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/download.py", line 36, in <module>
    from pip.utils.glibc import libc_ver
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/utils/glibc.py", line 4, in <module>
    import ctypes
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/ctypes/__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
    from _ctypes import Union, Structure, Array
****ImportError: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_ctypes.so: undefined symbol: PyUnicodeUCS2_FromUnicode****
```

Answer (score 2):

This is quite often a symptom of conflicting/erroneous Python installs, rather than Pip. I.E. they have been built and compiled differently.

Do you have multiple Python installations (or something like Travis CI installed/custom built installation)?

For reference - [here is a similar issue on the Pip bug tracker](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/4179)

I'd suggest checking what Python installation Python is referencing when you try and run it - you can use something like:

```
import sys
print(sys.executable)
```

And/Or look at using virtualenv to isolate the python environment you are executing against.

As another reference, I believe again similar issue to [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15403273/possible-conflicting-python-installations).

Comment: Thank you, I did a clean installation my system then only 1 version of Python was there, everything worked fine.