# ImportError: No module named numpy on OSX10.12.1

Tags: python, macos

My python version:

```
>which python
/usr/local/bin/python
```

Verified that `numpy` is installed:

```
>pip install numpy
Requirement already satisfied: numpy in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages
```

PYTHONPATH was exported:

```
echo $PYTHONPATH
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages
```

But when I use python and type `import numpy` it show the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named numpy
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you have more than one Python installed? I think the command line installation to the wrong location, May be due to virtualenv with non-system preinstalled python(e.g. homebrew, or macport)..

Or

Try uninstalling numpy and reinstalling.

[Look at the problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15401411/importerror-no-module-named-numpy)